# How to get other attribute except from 'value' request.POST.get("") ? Django

Tags: django, forms

I'm usuing `request.POST.get("")` with the name of the HTML tag and get the Value of the HTML tag.
However I want to get id/text .. how can I do it ?

Comment: What do you mean by "id/text". When a form is submitted, what's included in the HTTP request are key value pairs of form elements (`<input name="foo" />` etc.) and their values. `request.POST.get("foo")` gives you the value entered in the foo input. If you use Django's form framework and template tags, your forms will be rendered with appropriate names, but if write your own HTML forms, you have to make sure to include name tags for all form inputs that you want submitted. A input with only id and no name will not be included when the user submits the form.

Comment: If I understand you correctly the answer is no, you cannot get other attributes. Only the name and the value of the input are the things you can get. The "HTML tag" as you say is not actually sent to the server. If you want other data simply have them as a separate input (they can be hidden if you need, or you can use some JavaScript, etc.)